# SQL - Outerjoin 2 data tables with 1 lookup table

Tags: sql, oracle, lookup

Given the following structure:

```
create table region(
region_id number,
region_name varchar(50),
constraint region_pk primary key (region_id)
);

create table source_table(
ticket_id number,
region_name varchar(50),
constraint source_table_pk primary key (ticket_id, region_name)
);

create table target_table(
ticket_id number,
region_id number,
constraint target_table_pk primary key (ticket_id, region_id),
constraint fk_region_id foreign key (region_id) references region(region_id)
);

insert into region values(1,'north');
insert into region values(2,'east');
insert into region values(3,'south');
insert into region values(4,'west');

insert into source_table values(101,'north');
insert into source_table values(102,'north');
insert into source_table values(103,'west');
insert into source_table values(104,'south');
insert into source_table values(105,'east');
insert into source_table values(106,'west');

insert into target_table values(101,1);
insert into target_table values(102,1);
insert into target_table values(103,4);
insert into target_table values(104,3);
insert into target_table values(105,2);
insert into target_table values(107,2);

commit;
```

How to properly **full outer join** SOURCE_TABLE with TARGET_TABLE. Following doesn't work:

```
select * from target_table tt
full outer join source_table st
on tt.ticket_id = st.ticket_id
join region r
on r.region_id=tt.region_id
where st.region_name=r.region_name;
```

I struggle with the lookup in between.
Can someone help out?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: which RDMS you are using...?

Comment: Oracle, but I think in this case that doesn't matter. There certainly is a proper ANSI-SQL solution for it.

Comment: ..also mention your expected output..

Comment: as written, a full outer join between SOURCE_TABLE and TARGET_TABLE on the given primary keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that you describe the question, you need a `full outer join` followed by a `left join` with no `where` clause:

```
select *
from target_table tt full outer join
     source_table st
     on tt.ticket_id = st.ticket_id left join
     region r
     on r.region_id = tt.region_id and r.region_name = st.region_name;
```

I suspect this is not what you really want to do, but it seems to be the answer to your question.  This returns region information only when the id matches the target and the name matches the source.

Comment: Well, that is actually my desired output, I wanted to select those records according to the PK which are missing either in the SOURCE_TABLE or in the TARGET_TABLE. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

An example with the code easier to follow:

```
select * from 
  (select * from target_table tt join region rtt on tt.region_id = rtt.region_id) target_region
  full outer join 
  (select * from source_table st join region rst on st.region_name = rst.region_name) source_region 
  on target_region.ticket_id = source_region.ticket_id;
```